# noob WPF data binding - why isn't my DataGrid autogenerating columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Height="117" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

*** FROM WHAT I THINK I READ IN THE DOCS, THIS WOULD 
MAKE A ROW FOR EACH ITEM IN THE COLLECTION AND A COLUMN FOR
EACH PROPERTY ***

```
        <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="117" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="43,135,0,0" Name="dataGrid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="429">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

DATA

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Data
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Foo> Foos
        {
            get
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    yield return new Foo { Id = i, Name = "Foo" + i.ToString() };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

INIT

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGrid1.DataContext = Data.Foos;
        dataGrid2.DataContext = Data.Foos; // corrected thanks to post/answer
    }
}
```

RESULT

*Edit* After correction from poster (thanks!) I have the right number of rows but no columns. (this is what I was seeing before I put together this post and would have been the original question if I hadn't goofed up)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Try this

```
    dataGrid1.DataContext= new ObservableCollection<Foo>(Data.Foos); 
    dataGrid2.DataContext= new ObservableCollection<Foo>(Data.Foos);
```

And here's some useful material on [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx).

Comment: thanks for catching that, I goofed it up :)  I updated the question.